# How to upload file to OneDrive using laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-8, onedrive

I am a beginner with Laravel. I'm tasked with uploading files to OneDrive, but I don't know of any way to upload files. Anyone has an idea.

I tried searching GG and got some ways but I still don't get it. Can anyone give me any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Graph API to upload files to OneDrive from a Laravel application. Here's a general outline of the steps:

1. Register your application with Microsoft Azure to obtain a client ID and client secret.
2. Install the 'microsoft/microsoft-graph' package using Composer.
3. Obtain an access token for the Microsoft Graph API using your client ID and client secret.
4. Use the 'Graph' class to create a new 'DriveItem' object representing the file you want to upload, and set its contents.
5. Use the 'DriveItem' object's 'createUploadSession()' method to obtain an upload session URL.
6. Use Laravel's 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' class to read the file contents and send a 'PUT' request to the upload session URL, using the 'X-Upload-Content-Length' and 'Content-Range' headers to specify the size and location of the uploaded data.

**FOR MORE DETAILS:** [How to upload file to OneDrive using Laravel ?](https://noobgeekyy.blogspot.com/2023/02/how-to-upload-file-to-onedrive-using.html)

Comment: And how to access a particular file from a folder?